# Is There A Way To Mimic The <marquee> Tag In Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have some "marquee" coding on my HTML page. But, unfortunately, it does not work on some modern browsers.:(

I know how to get "blink" back using javascript. But, I don't know to do so with "marquee". Anyone out there got an idea here?

Let me know.

Comment: **Please reconsider the use of such an interface element.** Depending on its implementation, it is largely *disastrous* for disabled users that rely on screen-readers to browse the Internet. Even for users who don't use such accessibility technologies, such presentations provide very poor UX as the readability is very limited.

Comment: No need for JavaScript. It can be done with pure CSS. Just google "css marquee". BTW, such marquee effects are usually very irritating to the user.